# Distance between two iPhones

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation, distance

I'm trying to create an app which will allow me to measure the distance between two iPhones using the data from GPS. I have already achieved to find the location but I don't know how to make them exchange this data so as to evaluate the distance between them. Could you please help me to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the best way to do it is setting up a server (e.g. using Google App Engine) and make the phones connect to it to exchange their position.

Comment: That's what I haven't tried yet. I'm gonna go for it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose from peer-to-peer (sms, but this is not way you want) or client-server communication:

- something like project [FireBase](http://www.firebase.com/)
- XMMP server (Jabber)
- [CloudFoundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/), Google App Engine (as mentioned while I'm writing this), etc.
- own http server w/ database
- *probably a lot of next possibilities...*

Comment: i like the idea about own http server with database as I need to create it but not use somebody's product. Thank you. I'll try it.

Comment: ok, wish you luck. It's very easy but take some extra time ("somebody's" products - PaaS are quickier but own is own). You can choose from any language, very typical is Appache server + PHP + MySql. If (for example) PHP, you should consider to using some framework, i.e. _nette_ or now I began with _Slim Framework_ - it's very easy and quick solution for nice RESTful application

Answer (score 1):

you can use google distance matrix api for this, but it doesn't solve both user's position information exchange.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Answer (score 1):

You can use " getDistanceFrom " function in " CLLocation "

Comment: Yes, but how will I know the position of another iPhone? I need a link which will enable me to transfer this data and then I will use getDistanceFrom.

Comment: I think you HAVE to build a web service, and to identify iphones, you can use the UDID ( is deprecated now ).
my best solution ( to have an easy and secure webService ) is to use a Facebook identification : 
* Every time the user location is refreshed, you send this location to your data base and her FBid via this web service and you can find the other user using her FBid.